# DataTable delete multiple rows and Update with OleDbDataAdapter

Tags: c#

I would like to delete from a DataTable and Update the changes into my Database.

The simple case of one row works as expected:

```
CarRow carRow = MyDataSet.CarTable.FindByCarId(carId);
carRow.Delete();
odaCar.Update(new DataRow[] {carRow});
```

but If I have multiple rows then I get a **Concurrency Violation**

```
CarRow[] carRows = MyDataSet.CarTable.FindByCarType(CarType.Sedan);
foreach(CarRow c : carRows) 
{
    c.Delete();
}
odaCar.Update(carRows);
```

> "Concurrency violation: the DeleteCommand affected 0 of the expected 1 records."

What is the proper way to delete multiple rows and subsequently make the changes through the OleDbDataAdapter?

Comment: Do you have any other code that could me updating the records in either the DB or the dataset?

Comment: @Josh no. This is it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with the OleDbAdapter.

The DataSet I'm using doesn't have a Primary key, therefore I can't use the `Update` like that.

**Fix it by adding a PK.**